# Configure HTML title attribute in Struts table display

Tags: jsp, struts, title

I have used Struts2 to display my table's data. Most of my table data is too long and overflowed and i hide the overflowed data. But i can't use HTML title attribute to make it showing when mouse over, guess this is some restriction of Struts2.

Can someone kindly help to suggest me how to make HTML title attribute working? 
Below is my current code.

I tried add Struts title parameter, but failed.

```
    <display:table name="testCaseList" class="mobile" id="row" style="width:100%;">
        <display:caption><thead>
        <tr  class="pageHeader">
            <th style="width: 3%;" >No.</th>
            <th style="width: 3%;" title="Select All"><input type="checkbox" id="chk_selectedAll" onclick="selectAllTestCases(this);"/></th>
            <th style="width: 24%;">Test Case Name </th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Test Case Id</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Project</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Feature</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Component</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Test Type</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Automation</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Operation</th>
        </tr>
        </thead></display:caption>
        <display:column  title="Row Number" class="fixTitle1">
            <c:out value="${row_rowNum}"></c:out>
        </display:column>
        <display:column>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiCaseId" onclick="multiCaseId_clicked(this)" value="${row.testCaseId }" />
        </display:column>
        <display:column sortable="true">
        <a href="javascript:showTestCaseClick(${row.testCaseId });" style="color:#0059fd;">${row.testCaseName }</a>
        </display:column>
        <display:column  property="testCasealiasId" />
        <display:column  property="projectName" />
        <display:column  property="featureName" />
        <display:column  property="compName" />
        <display:column  property="testTypeName" />
        <display:column  property="autoName" />
        <display:column>
            <a href="javascript:selectTestCaseClick(${row.testCaseId },${currPage });" style="color:#0059fd;">Update</a>
        </display:column>
        <display:setProperty name="basic.show.header" value="false"/>
    </display:table>
```

Comment: `display` tags are not S2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Decorator for your display table. A decorator lets you create getters that match with "property" attribute of  tags. Then, you create a getSomething() method and inside it create the HTML code, for example a link or something and there you can add your title attribute or alt attribute which work for some browsers.